# How I can "atomically" replace function that is executed by trigger?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Here is code I have used to create `FUNCTION` and `TRIGGER`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inc_post_loves() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN;
  ...
  END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER on_post_love_create
AFTER INSERT ON "PostLoves"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE inc_post_loves()
```

Now I would like to modify `FUNCTION inc_post_loves()`.

If I will execute `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inc_post_loves()...` again, do I have guarantee that previously created trigger won't be deleted (like cascade) and it wont fail during replacing function?

Comment: Well, have you tried?

Comment: Even if I will try I cant check if during function replacement trigger will still be working...

Comment: Insert `PERFORM pg_sleep(60); ` inside the trigger function in a test environment so you get 1min to change the function while it's running. What you should see is that it works without any problem or error.